# Web component IE11 with Svelte

Tags: internet-explorer, webpack, web-component, svelte

I'm struggling as I'm trying to adapt webcomponents made with Svelte for IE11. I managed to show the webcomponents in the browser but I did not manage make them fully functional.

When using **Svelte transitions** I get the following error:

`object doesn't support property or method "__shady_native_contains"` in the @webcomponents file `webcomponents-sd-ce.js`.

I'm using webpack with @webcomponents polyfills.

Here is my courrent webpack configuration:

```
const sassCssConfig = {
    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
    use: [
        'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'
    ]
}

const resolveExtensions = {
    alias: {
        svelte: path.resolve('node_modules', 'svelte')
    },
    extensions: [".mjs", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json", ".svelte"]
}

module.exports = [{
    entry: ['whatwg-fetch', '@webcomponents/custom-elements', './src/main.ts'],
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        libraryTarget: "window",
    },
    externals: [
        {
            bc: 'bc',
            kendo: 'kendo',
            jquery: 'jQuery'
        }
    ],
    target: ['web', 'es5'],
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /(\.m?js?$)|(\.svelte$)|(\.ts$)/,
                exclude:   /\bcore-js\b/,
                resolve: {
                    fullySpecified: false
                },
                use: [
                    // Then babel
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                       
                        options: {
                            presets: [
                                [
                                    "@babel/preset-env",
                                    {
                                        targets: {
                                            browsers: ["ie >= 10"]
                                        },
                                        useBuiltIns: "usage",
                                        corejs: 3
                                    } // or whatever your project requires
                                ],
                                "@babel/preset-typescript",
                            ],
                            plugins: [
                                // plugin-proposal-decorators is only needed if you're using experimental decorators in TypeScript
                                // ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { legacy: true }],
                                // ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }],
                                ['@babel/plugin-transform-typescript', { "allowNamespaces": true }],
                                 ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", { regenerator: true }]
                            ],
                            sourceType: 'unambiguous'
                        }
                    } 
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.svelte$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                
                use: {
                    loader: 'svelte-loader',
                    options: {
                        customElement: true,
                        emitCss: false,
                        preprocess: require('svelte-preprocess')({})
                    },
                }
            },
            sassCssConfig
        ],
    },
    resolve: resolveExtensions,
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin(
            {
                patterns: [
                    {
                        context: 'node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs',
                        from: '**/*.js',
                        to: '.'
                    }
                ]

            }
        )

    ]
},

]
```

In my html file I have the following setup:

```
<script src="//cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/svelte-webpack/build/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<script>
  if (!window.customElements) { document.write('<!--'); }
</script>

<script src="~/Scripts/svelte-webpack/build/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>
<!-- ! DO NOT REMOVE THIS COMMENT, WE NEED ITS CLOSING MARKER -->

<script src="~/Scripts/svelte-webpack/build/bundle.js"></script>
```

As as side note, in main.ts I include the following for core-js / regenerator-runtime / promise-polyfill

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
import 'promise-polyfill/src/polyfill';
```

Has anyone encountered anything similar? I'm grateful for any help I can get on this subject.

Comment: I want to confirm with you whether your app works in other browsers or generates a similar error there? I suggest you click on the error message that will take you to the problematic line. You can post that line of code here, it can help us to find the cause for the issue. It can be possible that the file needs to transpile to make it work in the IE 11 browser.

Comment: Yes the app works in other browsers without issues. In fact the error occures only in the file `webcomponents-sd-ce.js`, which is dynamically loaded by the `webcomponents-loader.js`  from the @webcomponents polyfills. I got it to work, I will add the answer and a working rollup config file which may help other later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the whole thing to work with IE11. The problem was solved by replacing the `/cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js` file with `cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.5.7/core.min.js`. I can not tell what the differences are exactly, but the error is now gone.

Here is the working configuration in the head script as well as a working rollup configuration (typescript/babel/svelte/:

In the index.html file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.5.7/core.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/svelte-webpack/build/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/svelte-webpack/build/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/svelte-rollup/build/bundle.js"></script>
```

```
export default {
  input: 'src/main.ts',
  output: {
    sourcemap: true,
    format: 'iife',
    name: 'app',
    file: 'build/bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
   
    svelte({
      dev: !production,
      customElement: true,
      emitCss: false,
      extensions: ['.svelte'],
      preprocess: sveltePreprocessor()
    }),
    // compile to IE11 compatible ES5
    babel({
        babelHelpers: 'runtime',
      extensions: [ '.js', '.mjs', '.html', '.svelte' ],
      exclude: [ 'node_modules/@babel/**', 'node_modules/core-js/**' ],
      presets: [
        [
          '@babel/preset-env',
          {
            targets: {
              ie: '11'
            },
            useBuiltIns: 'usage',
            corejs: 3
          }
        ]
      ],
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
        [
          '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
          {
            useESModules: true
          }
        ]
      ]
    }),

    resolve({
        browser: true,
        dedupe: ['svelte']
    }),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({ sourceMap: !production, inlineSources: !production }),

    production && terser()
  ],
  watch: {
    clearScreen: false
  }
}
```

Also I added following pollyfills in my ts files as imports:

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
import 'promise-polyfill/src/polyfill';
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/*"]
}
```

I want to add as a sidenote, than I only switched to rollup to see if there was any difference. First I got the same error as mentionned above. So the answer really is the incompatibility of the polyfill.min.js with webcomponents-sd-ce.js in IE11, and not the bundling method.